# почему на почту приходит неформатированное смс

Tags: php, email

[image: сама ошибка]

Облазил не одду страницу хабра. как быть в такой ситуации?

Comment: Покажите как вы отправляйте письмо/смс...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Подобный вопрос уже был задан [вот тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11238953/send-html-in-email-via-php)

В заголовке $headers нужно указать тип контента text/html

php: `$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n";`

В противном случае Ваш email будет обработан как обычный текст.